# need help extracting multiple p-values from aov

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I know there are a lot of post about how to extract the p-value from an `aov`. However, I have a list with several thousand samples. i did an aov for each sample to compare two different treatments and now i am looking for a way to get a list with all the p-values, as i cannot copy them one by one..

is this even possible?
I had no problems doing this for the p-values created by a `ttest`:

```
results <- apply(data,1,function(x){t.test(x[1:3],x[4:6])$p.value})
```

data is my imported .csv and [1:3] indicates the columns that are compared with the columns [4:6]

so that really was not a problem, but it seems not to be possible to do something similar for the aov:

```
results <- apply(data,1,function(x){aov(x[1:3]~x[4:6])})
```

i cannot get a list with all the p-values (that are called Pr(>F)..which is kind of frustrating..
hope you understand what i am trying to do,

Answer (score 0):

```
results <- apply(data,1,function(x){anova(aov(x[1:3]~x[4:6]))[['Pr(>F)']][1]})
```

Comment: i do hope you can help me once more: it works fine when i compare columns 1-3 with 4-6 but i cannot compare 1-3 with 7-8. Do i really need equal sizes? because i only have a duplicate of the last treatment..

Comment: I suspect you are doing your linear model incorrectly. You have three classes, the first two in triplicate and the last in duplicate. yu should really be using lm(x ~ as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))), or words to that effect. nonetheless, you won't be able to estimate the within class error for your final class.

Comment: so i cannot compare those treatment using anova as they have a different number of replicates?

Comment: Not because they have a different number of replicates. Because you shouldn't try to estimate sd with so few samples. Try the lm code I just gave you, anova(lm(...)) will give you the analysis you need, but your CIs will be so wide as to make it pointless. Can't you just replicate your experiment/data acquisition? (and accept the answer if it solved your original problem) btw, elementary stats questions aren't stackoverflow material

Answer (score 0):

Youll probably want `lapply` if the data is in a list already.  And you can use `summary` to get the p-values from `aov`

```
lapply(yourData, function(x){
    av <- aov(yourFormula, data = x)
    summary(av)[[1]][,5]
})
```

Comment: well, apply is working..so does it make any difference to use lapply(regarding the results?)

Comment: Generally, `apply` is used to apply a function to margins of an array or matrix, while `lapply` applies a function iteratively through a list.